# Why does SQL Server sometimes choose an index scan over a bookmark lookup?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

we have a straightforward table such as this:

```
OrderID primary key / clustered index
CustomerID foreign key / single-column non-clustered index
[a bunch more columns]
```

Then, we have a query such as this:

```
SELECT [a bunch of columns]
FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerID = 1234
```

We're finding that sometimes SQL Server 2008 R2 does a seek on the non-clustered index, and then a bookmark lookup on the clustered index (we like this - it's plenty fast).

But on other seemingly random occasions, SQL Server instead does a scan on the clustered index (very slow - brings our app to a crawl - and it seems to do this at the busiest hours of our day).

I know that we could (a) use an index hint, or (b) enhance our non-clustered index so that it covers our large set of selected columns.  But (a) ties the logical to the physical, and regarding (b), I've read that an index shouldn't cover too many columns.

I would first love to hear any ideas why SQL Server is doing what it's doing. Also, any recommendations would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are those *random occasions* also querying using a single `CustomerID` or are you querying for several rows at once? The bookmark lookup is a pretty expensive operation, so the tipping point to when a scan is faster is quite low - much lower than most folks expect

Comment: Thanks everyone. You've helped me realize that our issue is probably that _many_ Orders can be returned for a single Customer - making the query non-selective.

Comment: So I think we'll create a covering index - covering the 12 or so fields that are returned. Yet (to me) a shortcoming with this is the possibility for us to add a field to the query, and forget to expand the covering index. I guess we'll need to comment our query with a forget-me-not. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selectivity of `CustomerID` will play some part in the query optimiser's decision. If, on one hand, it was unique, then an equality operation will yield at most one result, so a SEEK/LOOKUP operation is almost guaranteed. If, on the other hand, potentially hundreds or thousands of records will match a value for CustomerID, then a clustered-index scan may seem more attractive.

You'd be surprised how selective a filter has to be to preclude a scan. I can't find the article I originally pulled this figure from, but if CustomerID 1234 will match as little as 4% of the records in the table, a scan on the clustered index may be more efficient, or at least appear that way to the optimiser (which doesn't get it right 100% of the time).

It sounds at least plausible that the statistics kept on the non-clustered index on CustomerID is causing the optimiser to toggle between seek/scan based on the selectivity criteria.

You may be able to coax the optimiser towards use of the index by introducing a JOIN or EXISTS operation:

```
-- Be aware: this approach is untested
select o.*
  from Orders o
       inner join Customers c on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
 where c.CustomerID = 1234;
```

Or:

```
-- Be aware: this approach is untested
select o.*
  from Orders o
 where exists (select 1
                 from Customers c
                where c.CustomerID = 1234 and
                      o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID);
```

Also be aware that with this `EXISTS` approach, if you don't have an index on the "join" predicate (in this case, the CustomerID field) in **both** tables then you will end up with a nested loop which is *painfully* slow. Using inner joins seems much safer, but the `EXISTS` approach has its place from time to time when it can exploit indexes.

These are just suggestions; I can't say if they will be effective or not. Just something to try, or for a resident expert to confirm or deny.

Answer (score 4):

You should make your index a [covered index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964133%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) so that the bookmark lookup is not required. This is the potentially expensive operation which may be causing the query optimiser to ignore your index.

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or above, you can add them as [included columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx), otherwise you would have to add them as additional key columns.

A covered index always performs better than a noncovered index, particularly for nonselective queries.

Comment: +1 good recommendation - if it is possible to create a query that can be covered by an index